# I need help solving upgrade problem, "fetching upgrade failed," 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, update-manager

I am using xfce4 on an Acer c70 Chromebook.  I managed to successfully update my system to 14.04 about a month ago using update manager, but was left with many unresolved bugs that I could not work around. So, defeated, I decided to reset everything and do a fresh install.
On attempting to update 12.04 to 12.10, I get errors in both update manager and terminal indicating a "failure to fetch" due to network problems. I have gone through an exhaustive list of help pages trying to solve this problem, but thus far either none are pertinent to my specific problem or i am unable to understand how to accomplish the steps involved.

I am able to  `apt-get update`, and  `apt-get upgrade`,  but  `do-release-upgrade` yields the following:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]                                           
Err Upgrade tool                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]                                           
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                        
WARNING:root:file 'quantal.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Comment: 12.10 has reached EOL, and you can't (and shouldn't) upgrade to it.

Comment: how then do i get to 14.04?

Comment: thanks for your responses, but that returns the same error:  
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]                                           
Err Upgrade tool                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]                                           
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                        
WARNING:root:file 'quantal.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.

Comment: You are running 12.04.4, right? `do-release-upgrade` should have seen that the next version is Trusty.

Comment: correct, yes i am.  but it does not.  it displays the text i showed above.

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/504846/upgrading-from-12-04-3-lts-to-14-04-1-lts-failure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same problem 3 days ago and you have two options (considering your network connection is fine).

First option is go [HERE](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) choose your country etc. and mark your version of Ubuntu as 14.04. Then paste generated list into `/etc/apt/sources.list` (better backup first). Then run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y` then run `do-release-upgrade`. It's highly possible that you also have to repair `grub` after that. And to do that you will need bootable CD or USB, so you simply can run your update from Live CD. And that is the second option.

Comment: this looks like it will work, though it's offering me only a "partial update," i'm going to go ahead with it.  thanks very much, i will update with my outcome.

Comment: seems to have worked quite well, thanks again @michał

Answer (score 4):

You should set source.list to EOL repositories as described here: [End of Life Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

i.e. to something like

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME main restricted universe multiverse
```

maybe you need additionally change value of "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" from  "For long-term support version" to "For any new version". After that "Software updater" allow you to upgrade to next available version.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error and this is how I resolved it .

```
root@ub-lab:~# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Err Upgrade tool
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Fetched 198 B in 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'xenial.tar.gz' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

This will help only if you have network problem and you are not able to download the root file

search for the error message and mark the file which is missing. In my case its `xenial.tar.gz`

Then open the file `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts` and you will see the url where the file `xenial.tar.gz` is located.

In my case its `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/xenial.tar.gz`

So download the file with other internet option, where you don't have any restrictions and put this file on server

I placed it in `/tmp/xenial.tar.gz` and now update the url in `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts` for file `xenial.tar.gz` and point it to local.

in my case its file: `/tmp/xenial.tar.gz`

That's it. Then run:

```
do-release upgrade
```

It starts working and takes file from local file system and continues the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It might be enough to just purge and reinstall update manager. It worked for me, having the exact same error message. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/525524/327808).

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts` and add the information for the specific release. In my case it was:

```
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/bionic.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/bionic.tar.gz.gpg
```

(i didn't have these lines)

Then run the update and everything will work.