# Why does do-release-upgrade on 12.04 system not find 14.04.1 upgrade?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lts

I saw an article that 14.04.1 was released today so I went to update an LTS machine but it didn't find an update.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

What's the criteria for getting upgrades for LTS releases?

Comment: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/25/ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-released/ says users of 12.04 will soon be offered this upgrade. Wait a couple of days.

Comment: @bain9 Not a duplicate, questions are on different Ubuntu version.  The other question asked for an upgrade to 14.04 which is not supported by the `do-release-upgrade` tool.

Comment: @Emmanuel how are they different Ubuntu versions? Both questions are asking to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04.

Comment: @AlaaAli This question 14.04.1 (14.04 update 1). Other question 14.04 no update. Version number are different, answer are different.

Answer (score 5):

LTS releases are aimed at people who desire stability over the latest features.  For this reason we want to establish that the next LTS release is stable before its made available.

This happens with the first point i.e. When we release Ubuntu 14.04.1

This happened today 25 July 2014 as you can see from this [release announcement](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/25/ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-released/) on [the fridge](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/).

In the next few days you will start seeing an option to upgrade when you run the Update Manager.

There is no urgent need for you to update yet however.  Ubuntu 12.04 is supported till April 2017 and you can upgrade any time from when the Update manger first offers you 14.01 (some time in the next few days) till just before the current LTS release goes EOL.

Comment: Your comment regarding support is a little ambiguous, as some HWE's will start expiring much sooner than 2017:

"Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
on 08/07/14.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel
and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available."

Comment: Can you find  link to support your statement? My date for Ubuntu 12.04 is for Ubuntu. I fully accept the other flavours such as Kubuntu & Lubuntu may have a different schedule.

Comment: @Warren Hill: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

Comment: I'm confused that two days later http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts still doesn't include 14.04.1.

Comment: That's the message I get when I login to one of my production boxes which is running 12.04.4. 

Note this relates to Hardware Enablement Stacks specifically, rather than Precise in general.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HweStackEolNotifications


https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 0):

I just repeat my answer from [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501746/i-need-help-solving-upgrade-problem-fetching-upgrade-failed-12-04-to-12-10/501784#501784) ;)

I got the same problem 3 days ago and you have two options (considering your network connection is fine).

First option is go [HERE](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) choose your country etc. and mark your version of Ubuntu as 14.04. Then paste generated list into `/etc/apt/sources.list` (better backup first). Then run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y` then run `do-release-upgrade`. It's highly possible that you also have to repair `grub` after that. And to do that you will need bootable CD or USB, so you simply can run your update from Live CD. And that is the second option.

Comment: And it's now officially http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-released

Answer (score -2):

**To get Ubuntu 14.04.1**

```
   sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: The question was asking about an online update of a 12.04 system, not doing a fresh install.

Comment: NO, especially in a server environment, this is not a prefered solution. `do-release-upgrade -d` will not install the stable LTS upgrade but a development version.