# how to download 14.04 upgrade as iso

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, iso

i am using 12.04 LTS and now i want to upgrade to 14.04

I want to know , how to download the upgrade( only the upgrade files ) and upgrade process. My upgrade manager program shows 12.10 upgrade only. So that's why i am asking for another method. Would please explain me.I am not an experienced ubuntu user,Thank you!

Comment: Wait a couple of days. 14.04.1 will become available through Update Manager.

Comment: There is a guide at the following blog. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501746/i-need-help-solving-upgrade-problem-fetching-upgrade-failed-12-04-to-12-10/501784#501784

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to upgrade from your current install, just go to:

Software Center > Edit menu > Sources

And in the Updates tab, the last option (Notify me for new ubuntu releases) change it to: Only show LTS releases. That was as @muru said you will see the upgrade aviable (14.04.1 was suposed to be released on july 24 as iso).

Comment: i did it already. but it does not show any available upgrade. Please help me