# Can not upgrade from 12.04 using update manager

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Is there a special method to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04?

When I try to upgrade from 12.04 using `update-manager -d` I receive the following error message:

```
fetching upgrade failed. 
There may be a problem with the server.
```

Am I missing any steps?
Does anybody have a solution for this?

Followed guidance on ubuntu website for upgrading to 14.04. I read it to say that each release after 12.04 had to be installed subsequent to installing next release to finally get 14.04 installed. Did not understand that un-supported releases are moved to a different server and are essentially unusable, hence the error message that I received.

Comment: Try the command `update-manager -d`

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade to 14.04, or just upgrade in general? I would also like to say that while the help pages for ubuntu are confusing sometimes, they do work, it can just be hard to get it to :). Keep trying with ubuntu, as you learn more and more you will find it gets better and better!

Comment: A quick google search for "how to upgrade 12.04 to 14.04" gives this as the first result. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04

Comment: A second search on your error message gives this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501746/i-need-help-solving-upgrade-problem-fetching-upgrade-failed-12-04-to-12-10

Comment: @amanthethy, Was trying to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04. Was lead to believe from the ubuntu tutorials on ubuntu site that I had to progressively upgrade to each release version to get to 14.04. After reviewing the google search results that you pasted I'll give it a try. Many, many thanx for your assistance. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a summary of what I've found. We've no idea what you've tried so far as troubleshooting so don't get upset if this is something you've already attempted.

1. Visit [HERE](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and generate the appropriate sources list. For your case, Your Country and Ubuntu 14.04 (the version you're trying to upgrade to)
2. Open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Replace the contents with your newly generated sources list.
3. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && update-manager -d`

Comment: This answer isn't anything new. I've basically stolen another poster's answer and rewritten it here for you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/501746/i-need-help-solving-upgrade-problem-fetching-upgrade-failed-12-04-to-12-10