# Having trouble upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 lts to 14.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I am still relatively a newbie working with Ubuntu, and my current setup is having issues. I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 lts, 32-bit, a dual-boot system with Windows XP 64 bit, 2.9 GiB, Intel Core 2, GeForce 9600, 577.8 GB. My system often (at least 2-3 times a day) crashes and restarts. When it crashes, the mouse and the keyboard do not work, and if audio is playing it will skip for about 30 secs until the computer restarts. I've been working on the crashing problem for a while now, with little success.

In any case, at this point I would prefer to just upgrade to 14.04.1 lts to see if that helps. Update Manager is not notifying me of any new lts releases, so I am trying to upgrade via Terminal. But when I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

an error occurs with the update. Here is the last bit of what the terminal says:

```
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty-proposed/partner Translation-en
...
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Error during update
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/partner/source/Sources
...
Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
=== Command detached from window (Mon Aug  4 12:28:37 2014) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Aug  4 12:28:37 2014) ===
```

What would be the best next step after this? My internet connection is fine while browsing for solutions to the problem, so how could it be a network problem? I've tried this command a few times over the past couple of days, and I always have the same result. I've also tried sudo do-release-upgrade -p, and the results seem identical. Also, for the crashing problem, I also wonder if part of the problem is that my ubuntu system is 32 bit and my Windows XP system is 64bit. Is there a way to update to Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit without having to do a clean install? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered something similar a few days back. Have you tried the solution at this link? http://askubuntu.com/questions/504125/can-not-upgrade-from-12-04-using-update-manager?noredirect=1#comment683920_504125

Comment: Though, if you're having that many issues with your system as it is, your best bet is to backup all your important files and do a fresh install of 14.04.

Comment: Thanks, amanthethy! I ended up just following your second piece of advice and doing a fresh install of 14.04. So far no problems, fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, but I just had the same Problem upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10.

```
...
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Thu Oct 20 12:02:18 2016) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu Oct 20 12:02:28 2016) ===
```

simply pressing 'r' to reattach to the screen solved my problem.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The package repository path doesn't exist:

http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/partner/source/Sources

you will need to edit your Apt sources.list to remove reference to that archive.canonical.com   precise-backports

Comment: How do I do this? Please [edit] to include it.

Comment: the link is broken