# update manager unable to detect internet

Tags: update-manager

My Ubuntu 12.04 update manager is unable to connect to the internet.

I was able to download updates a month back with my older internet connection.

Now with my new internet connection , I am able to browse internet/download using Firefox, but I'm unable to download Ubuntu updates.

`sudo apt-get update` gives:

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Connection failed
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: i was unable to post the complete fail notifications in terminal because of size

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, 12.04 No longer receives updates as it's status is End Of Life (EOL). You could upgrade to 14.04 (the next LTS) if you want to keep your machine up to date.

This can be done with the command `update-manager -d`. Or if that fails to work, follow the instructions here: [Can not upgrade from 12.04 using update manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504125/can-not-upgrade-from-12-04-using-update-manager)

Comment: On running the command sudo update-manager -d             the update manager displays that it has checked and there are no updates to display              i feel my ubuntu was 12.04.4 LTS, hence i was getting updates for it until last month. the EOL for this version is april 2017