# problem upgrading 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade

im getting the following error while upgrading 12.04 to 14.04

W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Manager Error: Failed to fetch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36125/update-manager-error-failed-to-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like upgrade process is trying to retrieve Ubuntu Quantal (12.10) packages.

Apparently Ubuntu 12.10 is not supported since May 16, 2014 hence it's packages are not available.

Try following this advice: [Upgrading from 12.04.3 LTS to 14.04.1 LTS failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504846/upgrading-from-12-04-3-lts-to-14-04-1-lts-failure)