# 14.04.5 to 16.04 Update failed - xenial.tar.gz.gpg missing

Tags: 16.04, do-release-upgrade

The update from Trusty to Xenial is officially available via the software updater. After updating all packages, upgrading through the software updater yields:

```
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Doing a `sudo do-release-upgrade` yields:

```
    Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: xenial.tar.gz.gpg        
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: xenial.tar.gz            
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Comment: Make sure everything is updated first by running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. Also try to change the download server to Main Server from the Software & Settings application.

Comment: Yes I have ensured I am up-to-date and tried different servers.

Comment: Take a look at these posts: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501746/i-need-help-solving-upgrade-problem-fetching-upgrade-failed-12-04-to-12-10, http://askubuntu.com/questions/504846/upgrading-from-12-04-3-lts-to-14-04-1-lts-failure/525524#525524

Comment: Unfortunately, I have followed the accepted answer in the first link and it is a mess now. I have managed to do some repairs by booting from a live USB and chroot-ing from there. I am -_supposedly_- on 16.04, but in reality I have both Trusty and Xenial on my machine with a hybrid GUI and low disk space.

Comment: I will see what I can do to get things up properly. If things went well, you may post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: the problem is in some local firewall that does not allow to download some file types.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136289/failed-to-fetch-upgrade-to-19-04 this question was marked as duplicate of this one, but it's not actually duplicate because I have the problem in that question, not this one. Where do I ask how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling the **apt-cacher** service and comment anything you might have configured in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-apt-proxy.conf`, then run again do-release-upgrade (ofc, first update and upgrade again).

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, if not in use, you may want to /remove/ apt-cacher.

```
$ dpkg --list | grep apt-cacher
$ sudo apt-get remove apt-cacher
```

Then go again with the do-release-upgrade.