# Failed to fetch upgrade to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, 19.04

I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.10 and tried to upgrade to 19.04 via

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool [1.214 kB]                                                                                                                                                      
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                                                                                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]                                                                                                                                             
Fetched 1.214 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                     
WARNING:root:file 'disco-updates.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Network connection is fine, I don't have any outages. I'm not too experienced with using Ubuntu yet, so instead of tweaking files I thought I'd ask first.

Edit: I don't know why I though I should use `-d`, but leaving that out upgrading works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [14.04.5 to 16.04 Update failed - xenial.tar.gz.gpg missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811370/14-04-5-to-16-04-update-failed-xenial-tar-gz-gpg-missing). Similar problem with different releases, could be a working solution for you.

Comment: I've tried to disable the apt-cacher according to [this tutorial](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/10/02/how-to-disable-the-apt-cache/) and then use `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but to no avail. :/

Comment: It seams your mirror does not provide the file `disco-updates.tar.gz.gpg`. Please change your mirror in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or show us the content of the file. A good list can be found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors ... You'll can check if the file exist under the following path: http://mirror.waia.asn.au/ubuntu/dists/disco/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/

Comment: Regarding your Edit: The option -d stands for 'upgrade to development release'. (Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html) ... This should not be the release you want.

Comment: Now actually duplicate of the other question, it's a different problem, how do I ask to open this question?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade;
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391552

If it doesnt't try

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
software-properties-gtk
```

Check the first two boxes. You may also want to change the server. This recreates the source list.

See [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

as the new user you are, I would strongly recommend you not Upgrade your ubuntu and instead download ubuntu form here : https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=FR&version=19.04&architecture=amd64

then open up Usb creator :

[image: ubuntu usb creator]

and the rest is basically plug and play.

I recomend saving your data to somwhere new.