# Failed upgrading 12.10-14.04, error with fontconfig

Tags: 14.04, apt, 12.10, upgrade

I'm running 12.10 on a VPS, and realizing it's not supported anymore, I tried upgrading. I followed a thread from the forum here, and did the following:

1. Updated the sources.list file:

   ```
   ###### Ubuntu Main Repos
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

   ###### Ubuntu Update Repos
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

   ###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
   deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

   ###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
   deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
   deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

   deb http://repo.ajenti.org/debian main main
   ```
2. Ran `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y`
3. This failed, complaining about fontconfig:

   ```
   Setting up fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
   Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
   See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
   dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   Setting up apt-utils (1.0.1ubuntu2.6) ...
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   fontconfig
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```
4. `cat /var/log/fontconfig.log` gives me:

   ```
   /usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
   /usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
   /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
   /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, no such directory
   /usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
   /.local/share/fonts: fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol: FcStrListFirst
   ```

I tried purging and re-installing fontconfig, calling `fc-cache -f` to rebuild the cache, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Changing the sources list file is not the way to update Ubuntu, even less to jump between releases.

Comment: :( I searched for how to upgrade and found this link where I followed the first answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501746/i-need-help-solving-upgrade-problem-fetching-upgrade-failed-12-04-to-12-10/501784 Is there a way to fix this or roll back?

Comment: I removed fontconfig-config with purge, and after that everything started working...

Comment: Could you please convert your last comment to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: Sorry it took me a while, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I removed fontconfig-config with purge, and after that everything started working:

```
apt-get remove --purge fontconfig-config
```

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)